# what is teaching kids the rules and exceptions in multiplication called?

Tags: arithmetic, education

I recall reading a website quite some time ago about the rules and exceptions of multiplication with regards to teaching children. For instance: `The result of multiplying any number times 9 will have a result where the digits add to 9` (1x9=9, 2x9=18 so on, but breaks at 13). It was something like that -- there was a grid and there were about 8 'rules' and 5 'exceptions' that would let you multiply any integer under 13 by any other integer under 13 -- I think.

What's this technique called? Is it a good idea to teach kids multiplication with this technique?

Answer (score 2):

These could be ["divisibility tests"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_tests) or ["sanity checks"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanity_check). The one for $9$ in particular is a special case  of ["casting out $9$s"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casting_out_nines).

I don't see why you say that it "breaks at 13": $9\times 13 = 117$, and $1+1+7=9$. What is true is that eventually you get numbers that add up to more than $9$, but if you repeat the process you will eventually get to $9$. For instance, $11\times 9 = 99$, and $9+9=18$, not $9$; however, if you repeat the process you get $1+8 = 9$.

Note that these rules don't actually *teach* multiplication, they just provide methods to check multiplication; they are also not definite tests: casting out nines does not detect all errors. For example, if you make the mistake of thinking that $9\times 9 = 18$, adding the digits to get $9$ will not disclose the error.

Comment: After 10 the digits add up to 18 if you look at them right; here's another for-instance: when multiplying by 8, the first digit always increases by 1 and the 2nd digit always decreases by 2 (8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48, 56...) except at 7 and 11. So there's an exception and rule.

Comment: I'm looking for a technique to teach my kid the patterns in numbers, hoping that it will get him thinking about math instead of just memorizing the numbers.

Comment: @jcollum: In my experience, that sort of things is better discovered by one-self than taught; otherwise, you are teaching him to memorize the pattern instead of memorizing the number, and you aren't really encouraging much, in my humble opinion.

Comment: you were right about the 9's tho: 9 x 235 = 2115 which becomes 2 + 1 + 1 + 5 = 9. Wow.

Comment: @jcollum: Yes: this is called "casting out nines", or the divisibility test for $9$. Every multiple of 3 has digits that add up to a multiple of 3 (repeat as necessary); for 11, alternatively add and subtract digits; e.g., 11\times 14 = 154, and 1-5+4 = 0$, a multiple of $11$. Etc.

Comment: "Note that these rules don't actually teach multiplication" I couldn't possibly agree more. When teaching elementary mathematics, one should be seeking unity as much as possible. Taking the single concept of multiplication and breaking it into a dozen rules intended for memorization is about the worst thing you can do for a child.

Comment: @jcollum, there are many checking methods,and also some ways to check multiplication by plus-minus, while adding-to-9 is just frequently used. Your another instance is quite insteresting, maybe you could plot it and see the pattern:)